# rankOf operation in Sequence ADT

Tags: arrays, data-structures, big-o, sequence, time-complexity

- In a sequence ADT using array how does rankOf(position) take O(1) time?
- We need to run through the array to find position and then return rank of it.So it should take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you heard that rankOf takes time O(1) in a sequence ADT, but that doesn't seem correct. The naive implementation of rankOf will take time O(n) because you have to count how many elements are less than the given element.

Hope this helps!